# dynamically change schema for some tables in entity framework using db first with postgres

Tags: entity-framework-6, postgresql-9.1, ef-database-first

i am using entity framework 6 in my web api project which is  database first EF with postgres.
we have say 10 tables, out of which say 5 are in central schema. but while login user select organization so on the basis of basis of that i want the other 5 tables to come from the some specific schema as per the organization selected(we have multiple schema containing same (say 5) table structure but different data)

while login i get the schema name so that is not the problem, but i want something to implement the above mentioned scenario.

Also the solution as mentioned in this awesome article
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=efmodeladapter
is not acceptable in my project as we dont want to add anything in auto-generated file otherwise everytime we need to  update that file manually whenever we do some update

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Devart.Data.PostgreSql ,Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.EF6 and Devart.Data- version 7.10.1013.0